# Validate SOAP message against WSDL

Tags: java, validation, soap, wsdl

Just like validating an XML file against an XML Schema Definition in Java is there a way to validate an XML file that contains a SOAP Envelope against a WSDL file?

Answer (score 1):

Some web service containers provide this functionality.  JBoss 3.0.1+ does this with the @SchemaValidation annotation:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-NativeUserGuide#SchemaValidation

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! I'm using Weblogic 10.3. I will check whether it has similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring-WS, this can be done by using an interceptor along these lines:

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="...">
        <bean id="validatingInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
            <property name="schema" value="classpath:/wsdl/schema.xsd" />
            <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
            <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </sws:payloadRoot>
</sws:interceptors>
```

With CXF, here is an approach:

http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIturnonschemavalidationforjaxwsendpoint%3F

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool developed by Ivan Krivyakov which validates the req or resp XMLs based on the WSDL and / or XSD provided. The tool is available at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182406/Validating-SOAP-Message-against-WSDL (requires you to create a login though.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know simple way. In our project we just copy and paste  element from WSDL to XSD file. You can write an util class which will make this work instead of you.

Comment: What we do at the moment is, validate the body of the envelope which is an xml against a schema definition and then wrap the SOAP envelope around it. But it's more like a hack and would be interested in doing it in a proper way.